# How can you measure the coefficient of elasticity of a spring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, home-experiment

I have an experimental task of measuring the coefficient of elasticity of a spring. Can you give me an idea of what to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint: Hooke's force law for a spring is $F = kx$, where $x$ is just a displacement in meters, and $F$ a force applied to the spring. You can measure displacement using a ruler, and you know the force exerted by some mass $m$ due to gravity is $F = mg$. With that information you should be able to figure it out!

Comment: The force low can be also nonlinear $~F=k\,x^3~$

Comment: @Eli - of course one would want to use multiple weights, and probably also compression vs extension to see how linear it all.